# Will pytorch model.train() influence freezed layers?

Tags: pytorch

I saw some examples about freezing some layers of pytorch model, something like below.

```
for i, param in enumerate(Model.parameters()):
    if i <3:
        param.requires_grad = False
    else:
        param.requires_grad = True
```

But I am wondering when I put the mode into train model, i.e., using `model.train()`, will this function enables the `requires_grad=True` for all layers?

How can I guarantee the first two layers keeps frozen?

Comment: Putting the model into train mode will not unfreeze your layers. It simply changes the behaviour of different modules such as BatchNorm & Dropout, since they have different behaviour in train and inference time

Comment: How I can check if the layer is frozen successfully? I still find the model.layer.training is True somehow.

Comment: After you compute backprop (ie- loss.backward()) you can use the same 'for' loop you attached here and do: print(param.grad) . This will show you that the param.grad is None for the parameters you chose to freeze. This essentially means that there is no gradient computed for that parameter.

Comment: and `model.layer.training` is just a flag to change behavior between train and inference... and guess what? you can change that flag to `True` by calling `model.train()` or `False` with `model.eval()` :) but it means nothing to whether or not the model or layers are trainable.